# autoclick flash button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash, curl

Is it possible to autoclick a flash button? if so how would you auto click "select images" button on this web page:

http://johannesburg.gumtree.co.za/c-SelectCategory?CatId=9109

Answer (score 0):

If the flash has an ExternalInterface callback, you would be able to trigger it using javascript. However if it's a website you don't have any control over, you'd be very hardpress triggering stuff like that.

Comment: so the only way to automatically upload images there is using curl?

Comment: Serverside posting to gumtree might work, however I would almost guess they've prevented cross-domain posting. Maybe a greasemonkey posting-script will serve instead?

Comment: Looking at their code, they use some sort of token and stuff. I am not sure what would be the best way to upload pictures there. Can you may be look at the site and see if you can suggest the best solution?